# Meteor run android device error

Tags: android, maven, meteor, gradle

I'm trying to run my meteor application on my android device and am having some trouble. It was working fine until I added the `raix:push` package. After adding I get this error

```
root@sbhnmhmd-BB-83208B:~/Documents/whsapp# meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://192.168.0.2
[[[[[ ~/Documents/whsapp ]]]]]                

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be
         able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the
         same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to
         talk to each other (no client isolation).
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /home/sbhnmhmd/Documents/whsapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --device
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches
   com.android.support:support-v13:23+.
   Searched in the following locations:

   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/
   Required by:
   :android:unspecified

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
   --debug option to get more log output.


   /home/sbhnmhmd/Documents/whsapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
   throw e;
   ^
   Error code 1 for command:
   /home/sbhnmhmd/Documents/whsapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew
   with args:
   cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/sbhnmhmd/Documents/whsapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

The android SDK is up to date and I'm on Ubuntu 14.0.4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the support tools. Just one note though: cordova uses android sdk 22, NOT 23, so you need to have all of the sdk stuff installed for 22.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have updated/installed both Android Support Repository and Android Support Library using the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

It should work after this.

Read this [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/141) issue for more info.